# Calculate 1st Sobel derivative once in x and once in y direction and combine these two(for every channel)

Tags: c++, opencv, edge-detection

I need some help to figure this problem what i have right now.
I have 3 images that are the same only the the different things, is that they represent Blue, Green and Red. I need to combine them and get a colored image back.
I am using opencv and c++, but now i have this problem that i can't figure it out.

**NEEDED:** working on edge detection.

---- Update ----
I wrote some new code

```
  Sobel(img_r, x, CV_16S, 1, 0);
  Sobel(img_r, y, CV_16S, 0, 1);
  //Compute the L1 norm
  sobel_L1_norm = abs(x)+abs(y);
  //Find Sobel max value
  minMaxLoc(sobel_L1_norm, &min, &max);
  sobel_L1_norm.convertTo(sobel_image,  CV_32F, 255.0/(max - min), -min * 255.0/(max - min));
  threshold(sobel_image, edgeThreshold, min, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
  edgeThreshold.copyTo(img_r_edge);
```

I get this result [bad example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xr7Qf.png)

But it should be like this. [correct one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUNqR.png)

---- FULL CODE -----

```
Mat img_r = imread(input_path + "/01.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img_g = imread(input_path + "/02.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
Mat img_b = imread(input_path + "/03.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
// Edge Images
Mat img_r_edge = Mat::zeros(img_r.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat img_g_edge = Mat::zeros(img_g.size(), CV_8UC1);
Mat img_b_edge = Mat::zeros(img_b.size(), CV_8UC1);

std::cout << "Step 1 - calculating edge images... ";
  // TODO: 1) Calculate the 1st Sobel derivative once in x and once in y direction and combine these two
  //          (for every channel).
  Mat x;
  Mat y;
  Mat abs_x;
  Mat abs_y;
  Mat sobel_L1_norm;
  Mat sobel_image;
  Mat edgeThreshold;
  double min, max; //Finding min and max Sobel valuye;


  //---------------------------------------------------

  Sobel(img_r, x, CV_16S, 1, 0);
  Sobel(img_r, y, CV_16S, 0, 1);
  //Compute the L1 norm
  sobel_L1_norm = abs(x)+abs(y);
  //Find Sobel max value
  minMaxLoc(sobel_L1_norm, &min, &max);
  sobel_L1_norm.convertTo(sobel_image,  CV_32F, 255.0/(max - min), -min * 255.0/(max - min));
  threshold(sobel_image, edgeThreshold, min, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
  edgeThreshold.copyTo(img_r_edge);

  //----------------------------------------------------


  //       2) Normalize every gradient image and convert the results to CV_8UC1.
  //       3) Threshold the retrieved (normalized) gradient images using the parameter "edgeThreshold".
  //       4) Save the results in the cv::Mats below.

  imwrite(out_r_edge_filename, sobel);
  imwrite(out_g_edge_filename, img_g_edge);
  imwrite(out_b_edge_filename, img_b_edge);
```

Comment: _How_ would you combine them? I'd compute the `magnitude` for each gray image, and then add the 3 magnitude. (use float images to avoid clipping)

Comment: It should work with the function addWeighted.But i am really with no clue right now

Comment: I posted and answer with some examples. Note that I write down the code without actually trying it, there may be mistakes... but you should understand the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thresholding your `sobel_image` with threshold `min`.

However `min` will (almost) always be `0`, since it's the minimum value of the `sobel_L1_norm` image. Note that a pixel with no gradient will have a value of `0` in `sobel_L1_norm`.

The solution to this is to choose a meaningful value for the threshold. Since you normalize the values to be in the range `[0, 255]`, you can pick a value in that range (greater than 0).

If you normalize with values in `[0,1]`, pick a value in this interval.

---

You can use `normalize(..., NORM_MINMAX)` instead of finding the maximum and rescaling.

---

Also take care that `edgeThreshold` will be a matrix of type `CV_32F` after the call to `threshold`, so it will be also `img_r_edge`. To save the image correcly with `imwrite`, wither use `CV_32F` images in range `[0,1]`, or `CV_8U` images in range [0,255]. So you need either to rescale `img_r_edge` in range `[0,1]`, or convert it to `CV_8U`.

---

You're mixing a lot of OpenCV types here. It's usually easier to use `Mat_<Tp>` to know exactly the type.

You can always work with `CV_32F` images, with range in [0,1].

---

Code that will produce correct output, with suggested modifications:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    Mat3b img = imread(path_to_color_image");

    vector<Mat1b> planes;
    split(img, planes);

    Mat1b img_r = planes[2].clone();
    Mat1b img_g = planes[1].clone();
    Mat1b img_b = planes[0].clone();

    // Edge Images
    Mat1b img_r_edge;
    Mat1b img_g_edge;
    Mat1b img_b_edge;

    // TODO: 1) Calculate the 1st Sobel derivative once in x and once in y direction and combine these two
    //          (for every channel).
    Mat1f dx, dy;
    Mat1f sobel_L1_norm;
    Mat1f sobel_image;
    Mat1f edgeThreshold;
    double min, max; //Finding min and max Sobel valuye;


    //---------------------------------------------------

    Sobel(img_r, dx, CV_32F, 1, 0);
    Sobel(img_r, dy, CV_32F, 0, 1);

    //Compute the L1 norm
    sobel_L1_norm = abs(dx) + abs(dy); // Type 

    // Normalize
    normalize(sobel_L1_norm, sobel_image, 0, 1, NORM_MINMAX);

    // Use a value different from 'min', which will (almost always) be 0.
    double thresh = 0.5;
    threshold(sobel_image, edgeThreshold, thresh, 255, THRESH_BINARY);

    edgeThreshold.convertTo(img_r_edge, CV_8U);
    imwrite("img_r_edge.png", img_r_edge);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I know for that, but i need to do it this way without using magnitude method. I post some code i wrote yesterday, but my treshold give me the image white background, it would be black background and white 'lines'.

Comment: i wrote some new code above, if you like i can attached the main.cpp file so you can see for yourself.

Comment: Yes, it can help. Add it to the question

Comment: Ok, just a simple error... ;D I'll rewrite the answer

Comment: @twistedhat check now ;D